# Conflicting plugins break site

Tags: plugins, calendar

I have made a mistake: I switched on a Google Calendar plugin without switching off another, making the site stop working.

How can I fix this? Should I remove one of the plugins and restart the MySQL/Apache stack?

Comment: You should disable one of the plugins by renaming its folder or deleting it. Restarting MySQL/Apache almost certainly isn't required, but it depends on what exactly broke things. If it's just a PHP error caused by a conflict then restarting won't be required.

Answer (score 2):

Try debug to see the error: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/. Check also wp-content/debug.log or any other configured log files for exact error.

If the site is not working (blank page), disable plugins (*just rename the plugins folder to "_plugins"*).

If you know which plugin is problematic go to plugins folder and rename the folder plugin: (*plugins/_the_plugin*).

At least I followed these steps last time and I was able to login in admin dashboard.